# IE , chrome browser issue - multiple div showing up as nested div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have this html that shows up fine in firefox  except in IE and chrome

```
<div id="snippets">
  <div class="snippet"></div>
  <div class="snippet"></div>
  <div class="snippet"></div>
  <multiple of these>
</div
```

Each div with snippet class is showing up as child of the previous one.
I have .snippet { clear:both }

what css magic do I need?

Any help appreciated

Comment: I hope you close the last div. If yes, you create the html code with a script or it's simple html code? Also can you provide your css and even better a live example at jsbin.com ?

Comment: @user your question isnot clear , if you can post the complete code ,we can easliy fix that

Comment: @ you should give clear on all the dvs..

Comment: if it is ok, can i just point you to the live site at http://caniafforditnow.com

Comment: @user , sorry i said you shouldn't give clear on all divs , let me look at your website

Comment: @user what is the problem in this website http://caniafforditnow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try .snippet{float:left:width:100%}

Answer (score 0):

it was an incomplete end tag 
@Sotiris you came close, I give you the credit